# Independent increments in a Gaussian Process

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, brownian-motion

Sorry if this is a naïve question, but if you have a gaussian process:

$$
X = \{X(t), t\ge0 \},\ X(t) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)
$$

Can you prove that it has independent increments?

If yes how? And if no, what other information you’ll need to have in order to prove it?

Comment: There's not much one can say: you have. Independent increments is not part of the definition of a Gaussian process (which, btw, includes much more than you have indicated) and it does not logically follow from it and therefore, by the rules of logic alone, the requisite information must be equivalent to independent increments.

Comment: By definitions Gaussian Process provides certain structure in the time-series, i.e., correlated and dependent series.  But one could impose certain independence structure with the covariance matrix for the increments. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673820/gaussian-process-with-independent-increments